# Using Javamail and Gmail

Tags: api, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am looking for a way to send mail using Javamail and the GMAIL SMTP.

[Here is a page which provides some code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

I have never worked with **Public Classes** before and also the page suggests that:

> To run this example, you need two dependency libraries – javaee.jar
>   and mail.jar, both are bundle in JavaEE SDK.

Can someone please help me set up this script so that I can bind it to an event such as, OnClick.

Also if wanted to pass variables into the class such as: To, From, Subject, Body, how could I do this?

Please advise....

Thanks

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) will help.

Comment: sorry a bit confused here..............can this object be used on my web page that I am building?

Answer (score 0):

The jars must be in your classpath at compile and runtime for this to work, this is true of any JAVA library (.jar/.zip)

From a command line you would compile with something like

javac -classpath .;path to javaee.jar;path to mail.jar myclass.java

and at runtime

java -classpath .;path to javaee.jar;path to mail.jar myclass

In an eclipse project you would add the mail.jar and javaee.jar to the projects as libraries.

This is pretty basic Java stuff here, I really think you may need to go read up a bit more on this, you will be including libraries as every day java development. There are pleanty of places to find out the fundamentals of this.

Comment: sorry a bit confused here..............can this object be used on my web page that I am building?